# Should I test functionality from gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rubygems, tdd

I'm working with the devise gem on a Ruby on Rails project, and I'm wondering if I should write tests for it or just assume that all third party code is properly tested on its own.

If I do write tests, should I just do integration tests or would it be reasonable to add a couple of controller and model tests too?

Answer (score 4):

It's common to assume that third party code is always tested.

For instance, if you create a Rails model using ActiveRecord, it doesn't make sense to test that calling

```
Model.create!(foo: 'bar')
```

creates a record with attribute `foo` equal to `bar`. Otherwise your Rails application will end up to have tons of duplicated tests.

However, it's a good habit to test the integration of your code with third party libraries, in addition to the specs for your own code.

Please note that with the word integration I don't strictly mean integration tests in the way that Rails uses them. For example, if you create a custom named scope and you write a test that creates a few records and tests that the named scope returns only the expected records, strictly speaking that's actually an integration test (despite it's defined as unit test in the unit test folder of the Rails project).

Answer (score 1):

If you are overloading the Devise controllers, then you should test all the functionality of the methods you are working with.

If we are talking about Devise, then I suggest you perform some integration + acceptance tests, because Devise is not very user-friendly with users. Had many problems with Devise, ended in hours of debugging, which could be perserved with some acceptance tests. Moreover, if you're using OmniAuth with Devise, then it would be a MUST to test.

And, it would be useful for you to write these tests, so that one day you may change your logging in logic, and then you cannot run the code you are writing without testing it.